# how to print junit log to the console when run via main class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have this code:

```
public class CacheOnlyTestRunner {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Request request = Request.method(Class.forName("linqmap.users.jms.UsersServerAccessCache"),
                    "getUserFillsCacheWithAllPropertiesWhenOnlyFlagReadModeCacheIsEnabled");
            Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
            System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful() ? "test passed===" : "test failed===");
            System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);

            //comment
        }
    }
```

I run a junit test from the terminal. It fails.

How can I see the failed assertion text, as I see it when I run in intellij ?

I see other logs, but not this one for example:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <2>
     but: was <26>
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:832)
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a [RunListener](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) and register it at `JUnitCore`.

```
JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
core.addListener(new YourListener());
Result result = core.run(request);
```

You may have a look at JUnit's TextListener: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/TextListener.java